# AngularJS Get words with a prefix from text box

Tags: angularjs, tags, prefix

I am trying to get words with a certain prefix when a user types into a text box. For example, let's say I want all words in a text box that begins with "@". How would I go about getting these words?

Comment: You could try using the `split()` method. I don't know exactly what your prefixes are, but this is a good solution to get an array of the words you are looking for.
Get a look [there](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the JavaScript `split()` method.
Let's say you get the value of a user input into one of your variables. You can use this method to get an array of String of the words that start with the prefix you chose.

```
var input = "@This is what the @user typed";
var splitArray = input.split("@");
// splitArray = ["This is what the", "user typed"]
```